# Expected { in body of function declaration | Swift | Xcode 7.2.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uipageviewcontroller

after I implement

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?


func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
```

Xcode tells me this error:

> Expected '{' in body of function declaration

https://i.stack.imgur.com/315n9.png

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: In understand, you are a new developer in swift. It will be much better, if you learn swift in full first.

you don't have any method body here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these functions expects a closure afterwards which returns a UIViewController? You will just need to include the following:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

return //name of your viewController
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

return //name of your viewController

}
```